# Show that if a self-complementary graph contains a pendant vertex, then it must have at least another pendant vertex.

Tags: graph-theory

> Show that if a self-complementary graph contains a pendant vertex,
>   then it must have at least another pendant vertex.

$\exists v\in V (G):d_G(v)=1 (\because \text{self-complementary graph contains a pendant vertex})$

$\implies \exists w \in V (G):d_G(v)=odd.(\because {\sum_{v\in V (G) }d_G(v)=2.\text{No.of edges}})$ I am not able to prove it has another pendant vertex.

Comment: Have your tried to construct a counterexample? You ought not to _succeed_, of course, but the trying may give you some ideas why it has to be true (if it is).

Comment: no. how do i proceed with the counterexample

Comment: x @MathGeek, if you haven't tried to find a counterexample yet, try that for at least half an hour before you declare yourself to be stuck.

Comment: okay. thank you